# How to pass multi-word string as a parameter to bq query command in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bq

How to pass the multi-word string as a parameter to bq query command in Google BigQuery?

**My Command:**

value="param1 param2"

bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
--parameter=param_value:string:$value \
"select @param_value"

**Getting below Error**
lahu_bhawar@cloudshell:~ (my_gcp_project)$ bq query \

> --use_legacy_sql=false \
>   --parameter=param_value:string:$value \
>   "select @param_value"
>   Error in query string: Error processing job 'my_gcp_project:bqjob_r26e14ba47326f8d7_00000171000bf599_1': Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "param2" at [1:1]
>   lahu_bhawar@cloudshell:~ (my_gcp_project)$

Comment: Hi Mikhali, value="param1, param2" - not working , getting same error

Comment: Yes exactly same

Comment: This is also not working, getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "$value" instead of $value. It must work.

Answer (score 1):

Below version for Google Cloud SDK Shell on Win

```
set value="param1 param2"

bq query ^
--use_legacy_sql=false ^
--parameter=param_value:string:%value% ^
"select @param_value"
```

[image]